# Multiple Vue forms with VeeValidate not working on the same page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vee-validate

I'm trying to use multiple forms with VeeValidate validation on the same Vue component and not having any luck. I've tried limiting validation to specific scopes but it doesn't seem to be recognizing them. The first view (register with 4 fields) works fine. However, if you click over to the login view, the validation doesn't show there but carries over to the first two fields of the register view). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://codepen.io/admrbsn/pen/qGrEqz

HTML:

```
<div id="mainContainer">
   <!-- Join -->
   <div v-if="!showLogIn">
      <h5>Join</h5>
      <p>Already have an account? <span v-on:click="showLogIn = true">Log in here</span></p>
      <form @submit.prevent="validateAndJoin('join')" data-vv-scope="join">
         <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
         <input v-model="visitor.first_name" v-validate="'required'" type="text" :class="{'input': true, 'is-invalid': errors.has('join.first_name') }" id="first_name" name="first_name" data-vv-as="first name" placeholder="Your first name"
            autocomplete="off" />
         <div v-show="errors.has('join.first_name')" class="invalid-feedback">{{ errors.first('join.first_name') }}</div>
         <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
         <input v-model="visitor.last_name" v-validate="'required'" type="text" :class="{'input': true, 'is-invalid': errors.has('join.last_name') }" id="last_name" name="last_name" data-vv-as="last name" placeholder="Your last name"
            autocomplete="off" />
         <div v-show="errors.has('join.last_name')" class="invalid-feedback">{{ errors.first('join.last_name') }}</div>
         <label for="emailAddress">Email Address</label>
         <input v-model="visitor.emailAddress" v-validate="'required|email'" type="email" :class="{'input': true, 'is-invalid': errors.has('join.emailAddress') }" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" data-vv-as="email address"
            placeholder="Your email address" autocomplete="off" />
         <div v-show="errors.has('join.emailAddress')" class="invalid-feedback">{{ errors.first('join.emailAddress') }}</div>
         <label for="password">Password</label>
         <input v-model="visitor.password" v-validate="'required'" type="password" :class="{'input': true, 'is-invalid': errors.has('join.password') }" id="password" name="password" data-vv-as="password" autocomplete="off" />
         <div v-show="errors.has('join.password')" class="invalid-feedback">{{ errors.first('join.password') }}</div>
         <button type="submit">Join</button>
      </form>
   </div>
   <!-- Log in -->
   <div v-if="showLogIn">
      <h5>Log in to Peterson's</h5>
      <p>Need an account? <span v-on:click="showLogIn = false">Join</span></p>
      <form @submit.prevent="validateAndLogIn('login')" data-vv-scope="login">
         <label for="loginEmail">Email address</label>
         <input v-model="user.email" v-validate="'required'" type="email" :class="{'input': true, 'is-invalid': errors.has('login.loginEmail') }" id="loginEmail" name="loginEmail" data-vv-as="email address" placeholder="Your email address"
            autocomplete="off">
         <div v-show="errors.has('login.loginEmail')" class="invalid-feedback">{{ errors.first('login.loginEmail') }}</div>
         <label for="loginPassword">Password</label>
         <input v-model="user.password" v-validate="'required'" type="password" :class="{'input': true, 'is-invalid': errors.has('login.loginPassword') }" id="loginPassword" name="loginPassword" data-vv-as="password" placeholder="Your password"
            autocomplete="off">
         <div v-show="errors.has('login.loginPassword')" class="invalid-feedback">{{ errors.first('login.loginPassword') }}</div>
         <button type="submit">Log in</button>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Vue:

```
Vue.use(VeeValidate);
var main = new Vue({
  el: "#mainContainer",
  props: {
    showLogIn: false
  },
  data() {
    return {
      user: {
        email: '',
        password: ''
      },
      visitor: {
        first_name: '',
        last_name: '',
        emailAddress: '',
        password: ''
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    validateAndJoin(scope) {
      this.$validator.validateAll(scope).then(result => {
        if (result) {
          console.log('Submitted')
        }
      });
    },
    validateAndLogIn(scope) {
      this.$validator.validateAll(scope).then(result => {
        if (result) {
          console.log('Submitted')
        }
      });
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: Just as a test I removed all the scopes and references to them... and it seems to work fine (both forms get validated as expected).  I wasn't able to get scopes working as they should though...

Comment: Do you have a pen? I tried that and it's not working: https://codepen.io/admrbsn/pen/wbJgYM

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the problem was my use of v-if. It was conflicting with the rendering of VeeValidate. A simple (but expensive) fix was to use v-show instead. Since I'm not loading much for each, and the toggle is more efficient, I'm sticking with it.